# run report through form

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

- what is the wrong in this?
- i am trying to run 11g report through 11g form but iam getting this message.

  > [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHcYY.jpg
- the report is working correctly from report builder.

  > [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CmS9.jpg
- this is the button in form

  > [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzKdq.jpg
- and this is the connect code.

  declare

  ```
  p_id paramlist;
  ```

  begin

  ```
  p_id :=get_parameter_list('tmpdata');
  if not id_null(p_id) then
      destroy_parameter_list(p_id);
  end if;
  p_id:=create_parameter_list('tmpdata');
  add_parameter(p_id,'paramform',text_parameter,'no');
  add_parameter(p_id,'p_1',text_parameter,:block2.t1);
  ```

  web.show_document('http://mohamed-pc:7001/reports/rwservlet?report=D:\test\pharmacy\med_by_company.rdf&userid=pharmacy/pharmacy@orcl&destype=cache&paramform=htmlcss');

  end;

Comment: Do you use `Page &<PageNumber> of &<TotalPages>` for Reports pages.

Comment: no i didnt use page number

Answer (score 0):

The crash no longer occurs when `Reports Server tracing` is switched off. This may be due to the size of the trace file and that there was insufficient `disk space` / `memory`/`cpu` available to create it.

The problem does not reproduce when using `rwrun` / `rwrun.sh` because rwrun does not run the request via the Reports Server, and therefore no tracing takes place.

It should be noted that Reports Server tracing can have a major impact on performance. It is recommended that Reports Server tracing is only enabled when diagnostic information is required to troubleshoot a problem with a report, an error or a crash. Report Server tracing should not be enabled by default, especially in a production environment.

Running a Report via `rwrun` Performs Much Faster Than Using `rwservlet` or `rwclient`

> Switch off Reports Server tracing by commenting out the xml tag
>   relating to tracing in the Reports Server conf file.
>
> Change `<trace traceOpts="trace_all"/>`
>
> to `<!--trace traceOpts="trace_all"/-->`
>
> Stop and start the Reports Server for the change to take effect.
>
> **Reports Server Configuration File :**
>   *The configuration settings for the Reports Server component of Oracle
>   Reports Services are stored in the XML file `rwserver.conf` and
>   `rwbuilder.conf`, located in the directory : `ORACLE_HOME\reports\conf`*

Comment: sorry i have no good experience with this problems so can u tell me where i can type this?

Comment: @MidoSaeed I edited with `Reports Server Configuration File`

Comment: look at comments plz